# Instead of react-script npm calling serve -s build

Tags: node.js, npm

When I'm in project root and open shell type npm start earlier is
`

```
 project@0.1.0 start 

 react-script... smth`
```

Now is

`

```
 project@0.1.0 start 

 serve -s build`
```

And I cant start my project

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When any `npm run <cmd_name>` is run in CLI, it checks the `package.json` file  `script` section. Similar way, if you run `npm run start` this internally calls the script present in the `package.json`. You can check there and make the cmd do something else.